# Cannot SSH to an Azure Virtual Machine from a certain IP

Tags: azure, networking, ssh

Up until two weeks ago I'd been happily connecting to a virtual machine hosted in the Azure cloud over SSH. All of a sudden, the connection could not be established anymore, the SSH always times out. The tricky part is that it only happens from a computer that is in a certain firm's lan (one public IP). Every other internet access connection works fine and I'm able to connect to the virtual machine successfully. My IT support tells me that they can see the packets leaving our network and the firewall is not blocking the connection - I can't see any failed login attempts in the SSH log on the server. The IT suggests the Azure may be blocking our IP for the SSH connection (other ports work fine btw). My question is - is such a thing even real? Can Azure block the IP without the user knowing about it? Is there some kind of IP blacklist I could edit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place where Your IP could be cutted-off is ACL on SSH endpoint. Go to management portal and check if You have any ACLs on SSH endpoint. Maybe You misconfigured some?

Comment: That would make sense, but nope, it's completely empty. I guess that pretty much means our infrastructure is to be blamed. Thanks.